# Vaadin guides - how to add them correctly

Tags: vaadin

Good afternoon everybody.

I am creating a sales system that looks like this until now.

[image: screenshot]

It shows my grid without any sales, as I am still implementing the system, we can also see the existence of 3 buttons (New, Change, Delete). So far so good.

When I click on the New button, a window opens

[image: screenshot]

With the window open as shown in annex 2, we have 3 tabs (Sales, Delivery and Financial).

Each tab must have its own form and each form must have its own components (ComboBox, TextField, DatePicker ... etc)

From here I have countless problems, all caused by my lack of experience in programming, after all it's only a few months since I started learning.

My first problem:

With the current code, if I click on any of the three tabs, the same form, with the same components are displayed (see annex 3 and annex 4).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

How do I ensure that each guide has its form and each form has its components?

See my code:

```
package br.com.fjsistemas.cadastros.view;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.vaadin.textfieldformatter.CustomStringBlockFormatter;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.GridVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.NumberField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.PropertyId;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.NumberRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import br.com.fjsistemas.backend.Venda;
import br.com.fjsistemas.main.MainView;
import br.com.fjsistemas.service.VendaService;

@Route(value = "venda-view", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Lançamento de Vendas")
public class VendaView extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private HorizontalLayout hltVenda = new HorizontalLayout();
    Grid<Venda> grdVenda = new Grid<>(Venda.class, false);

    private HorizontalLayout hltBarraBotoes = new HorizontalLayout();
    Button btnNovo = new Button("Novo");
    Button btnAlterar = new Button("Alterar");
    Button btnExcluir = new Button("Excluir");

    private Dialog dlgJanela = new Dialog();

    private FormLayout fltCamposVenda = new FormLayout();

    HorizontalLayout layoutGuiaVenda = new HorizontalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout layoutGuiaVenda2 = new HorizontalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout layoutGuiaVenda3 = new HorizontalLayout();
    HorizontalLayout layoutGuiaVenda4 = new HorizontalLayout();
    VerticalLayout layoutSeparar = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout layoutSeparar2 = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout layoutSeparar3 = new VerticalLayout();

    @PropertyId("data")
    private DatePicker txtDataVenda = new DatePicker("Data Venda");

    @PropertyId("nomeCliente")
    private TextField txtNomeCliente = new TextField("Nome Cliente");

    @PropertyId("telefone")
    private TextField txtTelefone = new TextField("Telefone");

    @PropertyId("celular")
    private TextField txtCelular = new TextField("Celular");

    @PropertyId("produtos")
    private ComboBox<String> txtProdutos = new ComboBox<>("Produtos");

    @PropertyId("quantidade")
    private NumberField txtQuantidade = new NumberField("Quantidade");

    @PropertyId("unitario")
    private TextField txtValorUnitario = new TextField("Valor Unitário");

    @PropertyId("valorTotalVenda")
    private NumberField txtValorTotalItem = new NumberField("Valor Total Item");

    private HorizontalLayout htlDlgBarraBotoes = new HorizontalLayout();
    private Button btnSalvar = new Button("Salvar");
    private Button btnFechar = new Button("Fechar");
    private Button btnAdicionarItem = new Button("Adicionar Item");

    @Autowired
    VendaService vendaService;

    private List<Venda> listaVendas;
    private Venda venda;

    Binder<Venda> binderVenda = new Binder<>(Venda.class);

    public VendaView() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        configuraTela();

    }

    private void configuraTela() {

        setMargin(false);
        setPadding(false);

        configuraHltVenda();
        configuraFltBarraBotoes();
        configuraDlgJanela();
        populaGrdVenda();
        configuraBinder();

        add(hltVenda, hltBarraBotoes);
    }

    private void configuraFltBarraBotoes() {

        btnNovo.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnNovo.addClickListener(e -> {
            novoClick();
        });

        btnAlterar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnAlterar.addClickListener(e -> {
            alterarClick();
        });

        btnExcluir.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnExcluir.addClickListener(e -> {
            excluirClick();
        });

        hltBarraBotoes.add(btnNovo, btnAlterar, btnExcluir);
    }

    private void excluirClick() {

        if (venda != null) {
            listaVendas.remove(venda);
            vendaService.delete(venda);
            atualizaGrdVenda();
        }
    }

    private void configuraHltVenda() {
        hltVenda.setWidthFull();
        configuraGrdVenda();
        hltVenda.add(grdVenda);
    }

    private void configuraGrdVenda() {
        grdVenda.setHeight("820px");
        grdVenda.setWidthFull();

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getId).setHeader("ID:").setAutoWidth(true);

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getDataVenda).setHeader("Data Venda:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("dataVenda");

        grdVenda.addColumn(Venda::getCliente).setHeader("Cliente:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("cliente");

        grdVenda.addColumn(new NumberRenderer<>(Venda::getValorTotalVenda, "R$ %(,.2f", Locale.getDefault(), "R$ 0.00"))
                .setHeader("Valor Total:").setAutoWidth(true).setKey("valorTotalVenda");

        grdVenda.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_COMPACT, GridVariant.LUMO_COLUMN_BORDERS);

        grdVenda.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true).setResizable(true));

        grdVenda.addItemClickListener(e -> {
            venda = e.getItem();
        });

    }

    private void configuraDlgJanela() {

        dlgJanela.setHeight("800px");
        dlgJanela.setWidth("860px");

        Tab vender = new Tab("Vendas");
        Div venderDiv = new Div();
        Tab entregar = new Tab("Entregas");
        Div entregarDiv = new Div();
        entregarDiv.setVisible(false);
        Tab financeiro = new Tab("Financeiro");
        Div financeiroDiv = new Div();
        financeiroDiv.setVisible(false);

        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        txtDataVenda.setValue(now);
        
        txtNomeCliente.setWidth("380px");

        new CustomStringBlockFormatter.Builder().blocks(0, 2, 4, 4).delimiters("(", ")", "-").numeric().build()
                .extend(txtTelefone);

        new CustomStringBlockFormatter.Builder().blocks(0, 2, 5, 4).delimiters("(", ")", "-").numeric().build()
                .extend(txtCelular);

        txtQuantidade.setHasControls(true);

        Label valorTotalCompra = new Label("VALOR TOTAL DA COMPRA R$:");
        valorTotalCompra.getStyle().set("margin-top", "112px");

        TextField campoValorTotal = new TextField("Valor Total da Compra");
        campoValorTotal.getStyle().set("margin-top", "100px");

        layoutGuiaVenda.add(txtDataVenda);
        layoutGuiaVenda2.add(txtNomeCliente, txtTelefone, txtCelular);
        layoutGuiaVenda3.add(txtProdutos, txtQuantidade, txtValorUnitario, txtValorTotalItem);
        layoutGuiaVenda4.add(valorTotalCompra, campoValorTotal);
        fltCamposVenda.add(layoutGuiaVenda, layoutSeparar, layoutGuiaVenda2, layoutSeparar2, layoutGuiaVenda3,
                layoutSeparar3, layoutGuiaVenda4);
        
        vender.add(fltCamposVenda);

        Map<Tab, Component> tabsToPages = new HashMap<>();
        tabsToPages.put(vender, venderDiv);
        tabsToPages.put(entregar, entregarDiv);
        tabsToPages.put(financeiro, financeiroDiv);
        Tabs tabs = new Tabs(vender, entregar, financeiro);
        Div pages = new Div(venderDiv, entregarDiv, financeiroDiv);

        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            tabsToPages.values().forEach(page -> page.setVisible(false));
            Component selectedPage = tabsToPages.get(tabs.getSelectedTab());
            selectedPage.setVisible(true);
        });

        dlgJanela.add(tabs, pages);

        btnSalvar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnSalvar.getStyle().set("margin-top", "180px");
        btnSalvar.getStyle().set("margin-left", "0px");
        btnSalvar.addClickListener(e -> {
            salvarClick();
        });

        btnFechar.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnFechar.getStyle().set("margin-top", "180px");
        btnFechar.addClickListener(e -> {
            dlgJanela.close();
        });

        btnAdicionarItem.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        btnAdicionarItem.getStyle().set("margin-top", "180px");
        btnAdicionarItem.addClickListener(e -> {

        });

        htlDlgBarraBotoes.add(btnSalvar, btnFechar, btnAdicionarItem);

        dlgJanela.add(fltCamposVenda, htlDlgBarraBotoes);
    }

    private void salvarClick() {

        venda = binderVenda.getBean();

        boolean adicionarLista = venda.getId() == null ? true : false;

        vendaService.create(venda);

        if (adicionarLista) {
            listaVendas.add(venda);
        }
        atualizaGrdVenda();
        novaVenda();
        txtNomeCliente.focus();

        binderVenda.setBean(venda);

        if (adicionarLista) {
            dlgJanela.close();
        }
    }

    private void populaGrdVenda() {

        listaVendas = vendaService.read();
        atualizaGrdVenda();
    }

    private void atualizaGrdVenda() {
        grdVenda.setItems(listaVendas);
    }

    private void configuraBinder() {

        binderVenda.bindInstanceFields(this);

    }

    private void novoClick() {

        novaVenda();
        binderVenda.setBean(venda);

        dlgJanela.open();
        txtNomeCliente.focus();
    }

    private void alterarClick() {

        if (venda != null) {
            binderVenda.setBean(venda);

            dlgJanela.open();

        }
    }

    private void novaVenda() {
        venda = new Venda();
        venda.setCliente(" ");
        dlgJanela.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the world of programming. You still certainly have a bunch to learn, but it is very good that you are jumping into something new and taking that challenge!

Looking at your tabs code. The tabs and the content seems to be okay. When a tab is clicked, you hide all contents, then you find the one that matches the clicked tab, and you turn visibility on on that one.

If I however read this correctly, `vender` is the tab button at the top, and you put in (somehow) all the form content into this tab header with `vender.add(fltCamposVenda);`. I think that row should be `venderDiv.add(fltCamposVenda);.

Now tabs seem to switch content between `venderDiv`, `entregarDiv`, and `financeiroDiv`, but they are all three empty divs, so nothing changes on the screen when you switch their visibilities!

Can I offer you two pieces of advice?

1: Consider coding in English. Even if it is not your native tongue, getting help becomes a bunch easier, and you won't mix two languages like Venda and VerticalLayout.

2: Consider splitting your view into smaller classes. Now you have a view, a grid, a dialog, a tabsheet, multiple forms, and probably more, all mixed up in the same class. Any part of this can access all other parts and cause unexpected errors, and understanding the code becomes harder. E.g. instead of `private Dialog dlgJanela = new Dialog();`, you could do `public class JanelaDialog extends Dialog {` in `JanelaDialog.java`, and then instead initialize it with `JanelaDialog dlgJanela = new JanelaDialog()`. This way you have the grid view in one class and the dialog component in another, and the code becomes easier to manage.

Good luck :)

Comment: Jens Jansson, I changed the code, but the behavior remains the same ... could you help me?